# Configuring Mamp Pro for SSL (not self-signed)

Tags: ssl, https, mamp-pro

I am running a website with a proper .com domain name from Mamp Pro. I'd like it to be accessible using https.

I bought a Comodo SSL certificate. I got Mamp Pro working fine with a self-signed certificate, but can't get it to recognise the Comodo SSL cert and key files. When I select them in Mamp Pro's Hosts > SSL tab, the "Save" button greys out so I can't save the change.

It's as if the files are being checked and seen as invalid or something.

The Comodo SSL cert came as a ZIP file with four certificate files: one for my domain and 3 "intermediate" certs. I combined the latter three into `PositiveSSL.ca-bundle` as per https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/installing-comodo-positivessl-certificate-bundled-with-root-and-intermediate-ca-certificates-on-apache but don't know where to tell Mamp about this file.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it appears Mamp Pro isn't capable of using the Comodo SSL cert.

At this point, Mamp Pro is still running Apache 2.2, but Apache < 2.4.8 does not accept the certificate and CA bundle combined in a single file.